# Can Stellar Assets be transferred to an un-trusting account?

Tags: assets

The Stellar documentation makes it clear that I cannot acquire Assets frm the issuer without first creating a trustline to the issuer.

But once I have the assets, can they be sent to any other account? or does the target account need to create a trustline first?

in other words:

1. I create a trust line with Issuer.
2. I receive assets from the Issuer.
3. I create another (new) account.
4. Can I send my Assets to the new account? Or does it have to first establish a trustline with the Issuer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each account must have a trustline set before they will accept receiving the asset.

> When you hold an asset, you must trust the issuer to properly redeem its credit. Since users of Stellar will not want to trust just any issuer, accounts must explicitly trust an issuing account before they’re able to hold the issuer’s credit.

This is due for a couple of reasons.

- It allows the account owner to set how much they trust the asset issuer (anchor)
- It allows the asset issuer (anchor) to limit or approve which accounts can hold the asset

> As an anchor, you can mark the issuing account AUTHORIZATION REQUIRED. With this setting, the anchor must approve anyone who wants to hold its credit, allowing it to control who its customers are.

You can use this link for a reference to where this is all specified:
https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#trustlines

Answer (score 0):

4. You can make a claimable balance. At the end of the day to receive an asset a trustline has to be signed for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).